# CSS 100% is not being respected when I zoom

Tags: html, css

I want to have a yellow rectangle **#box-over** across the entire screen at width 100%. 
At default zoom level on **Google Chrome** (I've not tried all browsers) it works fine unless I zoom in beyond 300% or so then that yellow box no longer is 100% of the screen it gets clipped and a horizontal scroll bar appears at the bottom.
I can't seem to figure out how to fix this behavior.

**JSFIDDLE**
http://jsfiddle.net/VySGL/1/

**SCREENSHOT**
[image]

**SOURCE**

```
        <style type="text/css">
        body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            background-color: black;
        }

        #box {
            width: 100%;
            position: relative;
        }

        #box #box-over {
            z-index: 1;
            width: 100%;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: yellow;
            position: absolute;
            top:10px;
            opacity:0.8;

        }           

        #box #box-over .box-column {
            width: 900px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            zoom: 1;
            position: relative;
            height: 50px;
        }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="box">
            <div id="box-over">
                <div class="box-column">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative for using 100% width is to set left and right to 0 in CSS like this...

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VySGL/4/)

```
#box #box-over {
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    top:10px;
    opacity:0.8;

}           

#box #box-over .box-column {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    zoom: 1;
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Using the left and right properties ensure you never exceed 100% width even when you add padding (See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VySGL/6/)).

For example when you add padding to your div it will be 100% plus the padding. See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VySGL/5/)

Comment: Love this even more! Because with the other method if I look at it on a small screen its so smashed up it's unreadable, this allows for content to remain organised and scrollbar to show. Thanks so much to both!

Comment: can I clear an absolute div? or is my only option to offset the next div with margin-top?

Answer (score 1):

Your inner `900px` div overflows the outer div's `100%` width when you zoom. You can give a `max-width:100%` to `.box-column`:

```
#box #box-over .box-column {
    [...]
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/VySGL/2/)

This will force the inner div to respect the container's width.

Another solution is to set the `#box-over`'s `overflow` to `hidden` or `scroll`. This way the inner div will still have `900px` width equivalent in aspect ratio.

Comment: Fantastic the max-width works thank you! I am trying to understand though how is that possible that the box-over overflows a 100% width, how does that work.  http://jsfiddle.net/VySGL/7/

Comment: @user391986 It is simple, by definition an inner `div` with defined width value higher than the container will overflow its container. You can check it applying `width:200%` to the inner element as well. That's why we have the `overflow` property to control how overflowing is handled.